# Passing an arg outputs file as null, program working if value passed during the execution of program

Tags: arrays, c, file, null, arguments

In a program for my CS class we're asked to read an array from a txt file and detect sequences of equal numbers in the rows or columns. I've done the program and it was working if it later on asks for the value that we store in "c" to see which number we want to look for in the array, but for some reason it does not work when I enter the value from the terminal (as an argument), outputting the file is NULL, when before it worked just fine.

This is the code for receiving the value as an argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 5
#define square_location "square.txt"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int square[MAX][MAX], c;
    if(argc!=2){
        fprintf(stderr,"we're missing args!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(square_location,"r");
    if(file==NULL){
        printf("Woops!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d",&c);
    
    int i=0,j=0;
    
    
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<MAX;j++) {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &square[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
 
    printf("the file read is: \n");
    
    for (int i = 0; i <MAX ; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; ++j) {
            printf("%d ",square[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i <MAX ; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <MAX ; ++j) {
            if(square[i][j]== c && square[i][j+1]==c && square[i][j+2]==c){
                printf("sequence found at row %d !!\n",i+1);

            }

        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i <MAX ; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <MAX ; ++j) {
            if(square[i][j]== c && square[i+1][j]==c && square[i+2][j]==c){
                printf("sequence found at column %d !!\n",j+1);

            }
        }
    }
    
    
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the code before any modifications:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 5
#define square_location "square.txt"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int square[MAX][MAX],c;
    
    
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(square_location,"r");
    if(file==NULL){
        printf("Woops!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<MAX;j++) {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &square[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    
    
   
 
    printf("the file read is: \n");
    
    for (int i = 0; i <MAX ; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; ++j) {
            printf("%d ",square[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("enter the value to find\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i <MAX ; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <MAX ; ++j) {
            if(square[i][j]== c && square[i][j+1]==c && square[i][j+2]==c){
                printf("sequence found at row %d !!\n",i+1);

            }

        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i <MAX ; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <MAX ; ++j) {
            if(square[i][j]== c && square[i+1][j]==c && square[i+2][j]==c){
                printf("sequence found at column %d !!\n",j+1);

            }
        }
    }
    
    
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
the file read is: 
1 1 1 3 4 
1 3 2 4 1 
1 2 2 2 0 
0 2 2 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
enter the value to find
1
sequence found at row 1 !!
```

Comment: `square[i][j+1]` and `square[i+2][j]` etc. are reading outside the array bounds, so anything can happen. Which includes appearing to work properly too.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to edit it and see what happens